# AVAssetWriter error: Cannot append media data after ending session

Tags: swift, avfoundation, avassetwriter, avasset

This error occurs when capturing video with `AVAssetWriter`. However, after calling AVAssetWriter's `finishWriting` inside of `endVideoCapture`, there isn't another call to start writing again, so why is this occurring?

As you can see in the delegate function, `captureOutput`, we check the recording state before trying to append to the asset writer. The recording state is set to false in `endVideoCapture.`

> Optional(Error Domain=AVFoundationErrorDomain Code=-11862 "Cannot
>   append media data after ending session"
>   UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=The application encountered a
>   programming error., NSLocalizedDescription=The operation is not
>   allowed, NSDebugDesc

```
func startVideoCapture() {
    // Get capture resolution
    let resolution = getCaptureResolution()

    // Return if capture resolution not set
    if resolution.width == 0 || resolution.height == 0 {
        printError("Error starting capture because resolution invalid")
        return
    }

    // If here, start capture
    assetWriter = createAssetWriter(Int(resolution.width), outputHeight: Int(resolution.height))
    let recordingClock = captureSession.masterClock
    assetWriter!.startWriting()
    assetWriter!.startSession(atSourceTime: CMClockGetTime(recordingClock!))

    // Update time stamp
    startTime = CACurrentMediaTime()

    // Update <recording> flag & notify delegate
    recording = true
    delegate?.cameraDidStartVideoCapture()
}


func createAssetWriter(_ outputWidth: Int, outputHeight: Int) -> AVAssetWriter? {
    // Update <outputURL> with temp file to hold video
    let tempPath = gFile.getUniqueTempPath(gFile.MP4File)
    outputURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: tempPath)

    // Return new asset writer or nil
    do {
        // Create asset writer
        let newWriter = try AVAssetWriter(outputURL: outputURL, fileType: AVFileTypeMPEG4)

        // Define video settings
        let videoSettings: [String : AnyObject] = [
            AVVideoCodecKey  : AVVideoCodecH264 as AnyObject,
            AVVideoWidthKey  : outputWidth as AnyObject,
            AVVideoHeightKey : outputHeight as AnyObject,
        ]

        // Add video input to writer
        assetWriterVideoInput = AVAssetWriterInput(mediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo, outputSettings: videoSettings)
        assetWriterVideoInput!.expectsMediaDataInRealTime = true
        newWriter.add(assetWriterVideoInput!)

        // Define audio settings
        let audioSettings : [String : AnyObject] = [
            AVFormatIDKey : NSInteger(kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC) as AnyObject,
            AVNumberOfChannelsKey : 2 as AnyObject,
            AVSampleRateKey : NSNumber(value: 44100.0 as Double)
        ]

        // Add audio input to writer
        assetWriterAudioInput = AVAssetWriterInput(mediaType: AVMediaTypeAudio, outputSettings: audioSettings)
        assetWriterAudioInput!.expectsMediaDataInRealTime = true
        newWriter.add(assetWriterAudioInput!)

        // Return writer
        print("Created asset writer for \(outputWidth)x\(outputHeight) video")
        return newWriter
    } catch {
        printError("Error creating asset writer: \(error)")
        return nil
    }
}


func endVideoCapture() {
    // Update flag to stop data capture
    recording = false

    // Return if asset writer undefined
    if assetWriter == nil {
        return
    }

    // If here, end capture
    // -- Mark inputs as done
    assetWriterVideoInput!.markAsFinished()
    assetWriterAudioInput!.markAsFinished()

    // -- Finish writing
    assetWriter!.finishWriting() {
        self.assetWriterDidFinish()
    }
}

func assetWriterDidFinish() {
    print("Asset writer finished with status: \(getAssetWriterStatus())")

    // Return early on error & tell delegate
    if assetWriter!.error != nil {
        printError("Error finishing asset writer: \(assetWriter!.error)")
        delegate?.panabeeCameraDidEndVideoCapture(videoURL: nil, videoDur: 0, error: assetWriter!.error)
        logEvent("Asset Writer Finish Error", userData: ["Error" : assetWriter!.error.debugDescription])
        return
    }

    // If here, no error so extract video properties & tell delegate
    let videoAsset = AVURLAsset(url: outputURL, options: nil)
    let videoDur = CMTimeGetSeconds(videoAsset.duration)
    let videoTrack = videoAsset.tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo)[0]
    print("Camera created video. Duration: \(videoDur). Size: \(videoTrack.naturalSize). Transform: \(videoTrack.preferredTransform). URL: \(outputURL).")

    // Tell delegate
    delegate?.cameraDidEndVideoCapture(videoURL: outputURL.path, videoDur: videoDur, error: assetWriter!.error)

    // Reset <assetWriter> to nil
    assetWriter = nil
}

func captureOutput(_ captureOutput: AVCaptureOutput!, didOutputSampleBuffer sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer!, from connection: AVCaptureConnection!) {
    // Return if not recording
    if !recording {
        return
    }

    // If here, capture data
    // Write video data?
    if captureOutput == videoOutput && assetWriterVideoInput!.isReadyForMoreMediaData {
        assetWriterVideoQueue!.async {
            self.assetWriterVideoInput!.append(sampleBuffer)
        }
    }

    // No, write audio data?
    if captureOutput == audioOutput && assetWriterAudioInput!.isReadyForMoreMediaData {
        assetWriterAudioQueue!.async {
            self.assetWriterAudioInput!.append(sampleBuffer)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you calling `finishWriting`? If you need to pause writing, you could pause the capture session or not write the frames you receive - both approaches may require modifying the sample buffer time stamps.

Comment: @RhythmicFistman aren't you supposed to call `finishWriting` when done recording? The class docs are painfully scant on details; where did you see that calling `finishWriting` is not recommend? Also, we do discard frames if they arrive too late. If `finishWriting` is called already (i.e., user wants session to end), the code is supposed to discard future frames, which you can see on the first line of the `captureOutput` function. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Once you call `finishWriting` you have to create a new `AVAssetWriter` if you want to record something else.

Comment: @RhythmicFistman Yup, understood. That's not the issue. There is a sister call to `endVideoCapture` which starts the video capture, and inside this function a new `AVAssetWriter` gets created. Any suggestions?

Comment: Do the writer inputs get reset too? You should show that code.

Comment: @RhythmicFistman ok added that code. didn't show it originally since didn't suspect it as an issue and didn't want to bloat the question. thanks for your help!

Comment: Did you find where the problem comes from? I have a similar issue. When calling `finishWriting` to stop the recording, append(sampleBuffer) still get called on audio and video writer inputs and it crashes (NSException).

Comment: I re-added `markAsFinished` before `finishWriting` and I just had the same error as you > Cannot append media data after ending session.

Comment: @MarieDm does this crash happen consistently? are you using the same code to write video/audio data as in the question? in particular, are you using queues as the code above?

Comment: Hey @Crashalot I'm sorry it's been a while since the question was asked so I don't remember everything. I asked a most recent question where I pasted my code, so it must look like this > https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44135223/record-video-with-avassetwriter-first-frames-are-black I remember having way less crashes after I updated my code to this, but it was still happening sometimes (without much debugging info). I actually also wondered if it could be a queue issue, made some tests... But I don't know.