# How to create real-time video on iOS: Apple docs say AVAssetWriter not for real-time processing?

Tags: ios, video, avfoundation, real-time, avassetwriter

We have been to trying to create real-time videos on iOS, but have experienced many frustrating problems with `AVAssetWriter` [like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41647342/avassetwriter-error-cannot-append-media-data-after-ending-session) where the error claims media is being appended after a session ends, though our code does not appear to do this.

Upon reading [the Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/05_Export.html) more carefully, it appears `AVAssetWriter` is not meant for real-time processing:

> Note: The asset reader and writer classes are not intended to be used
>   for real-time processing. In fact, an asset reader cannot even be used
>   for reading from a real-time source like an HTTP live stream. However,
>   if you are using an asset writer with a real-time data source, such as
>   an AVCaptureOutput object, set the expectsMediaDataInRealTime property
>   of your asset writer’s inputs to YES. Setting this property to YES for
>   a non-real-time data source will result in your files not being
>   interleaved properly.

If not `AVAssetWriter`, how are you supposed to capture input from the front camera and make a video in real-time (with different overlays/watermarks appearing at different points in the video)?

Comment: Use AVToolBox to compress, and a third party library to package.

Comment: @szatmary could you kindly elaborate? there only seems to be an audiotoolbox? how do you recommend capturing video on iOS?

Comment: I think you missed VideoToolbox.

Comment: @szatmary ahh indeed. :) So instead of AVAssetWriter, you suggest using VideoToolbox and AudioToolbox? Are you aware of any working samples online showing how to use VideoToolbox and AudioToolbox to capture video from the front camera? There doesn't appear to be anything solid on Github or Google. To be clear, we don't need to stream -- just record and save locally onto the user's device.

Comment: You misunderstand the definition of real-time in this context. " just record and save locally onto the user's device" is not real-time.

Comment: @szatmary ok, makes sense! thanks for answering. you don't happen to know the answer to this avassetwriter issue do you (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41647342/avassetwriter-error-cannot-append-media-data-after-ending-session)?

Comment: @szatmary btw could you please post as an answer so you can receive the points? thanks again!